# Stay at the same page after reloading Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, reload

My `Anuglar 4` app has multiple routes, in below example there are only two of them - Logging and List of items. So basically there are two routes: `http://localhost:4200/#/` and `http://localhost:4200/#/items`. When I am at the `http://localhost:4200/#/items` and reload the page it automatically navigates me to `http://localhost:4200/#/` which from my point of view is wrong behaviour. Is there a nice way how to prevent it? And when currently I am at the `http://localhost:4200/#/items` and reload the page to stay at the same page?

Below I post kind of configuration which might help you:

```
<base href="/">

  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
      {path: 'items', component: ItemListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    ])
  ],

      providers: [
        {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomHttpInterceptor, multi: true},
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
        AuthenticationService,
        AuthGuard,
      ],
```

AuthGuard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService extends DataService{

  private _isLoggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
    this._isLoggedIn = false;
    this.url = '/api/auth';
  }

  get isLoggedIn(): boolean{
    return this._isLoggedIn;
  }

  set isLoggedIn(value: boolean){
    this._isLoggedIn = value;
  }
```

And the server returns the token. For your information after reloading there is still valid token keeping in localStorage

Comment: this has to do with the server configuration , you might need to set up your server to handle the refresh so that it will return the home page i:e index.html and the routes will take it up from there

Comment: Take out AuthGuard from the items route then try again to see if the problem persists?

Comment: @ChauTran I removed AuthGuard and it works. Is there any workaround to work it with AuthGuard ?

Comment: It has something to do with your app not getting the token from wherever you trying to get it to implement AuthGuard. Can I see your AuthGuard file?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: what strategy are you using for auth?

Comment: It’s a basic authentication by spring security. I put a token to headers

Comment: Try a simple canActivate(): boolean {return this.authService.isLoggedIn}

Comment: Oh what is the difference between mine and yours?

Comment: I am really not sure how canActivate works really. I use Node/Express in the backend and use `angular2-jwt` to check for the valid token in localStorage then return a boolean value to isLoggedIn. Then canActivate gets returned based on this boolean value, neither an Observable nor a Promise.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with authtoken, but all about your `canActivate`. When your app is initialized, means that app is destroyed and recreated. So when on a route that requires the logged in status, you have initially declared `_isloggedIn` as `false`. So the guard is working properly and redirecting you to your `LoginComponent`.

You would want to use `localStorage` or something else to persist your logged in status in case of page refresh.

Comment: This makes sense... Now to go find the localStorage working ;)

Answer (score 0):

add pathMatch: 'full'

```
{path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```

Answer (score -1):

Angular is a Single Page Application based framework. Page refresh will be done only when the app is initialized. You can make use of two-way binding, make a call to back-end and update the list of items received in response.
You can also try router.navigate(['/items']), it will work only when you are navigating from other components.

Comment: How it is connected to my question??

Comment: simple and straightforward, you cannot reload a page in angular.

Comment: I think you are wrong. Just push the reload button in browser and it will reload. That’s the case

Comment: it will reload but the whole application gets reinitialize and the bootstrap component( bootstrap: [AppComponent]) declared in app.module.ts will be loaded. so even if you are in /items when reloading the browser main component in your case /#/ will be loaded

Comment: Ok. I get your point. So while I’m using spring boot on server side just for rest APIs, how can I workaround this? Because it’s quite irritating btw.

Comment: tell me what exactly you need. why you want to reload the page

Comment: The scenario is quite simple. User works at my app, he does updates/inserts etc and suddenly he would like to reload/refresh the whole page (there's no question why). And after reloading/refreshin by clicking refresh button in browser the application should stay at the same page on which user was when he clicked the refresh button. Do you understand me more than less?

Comment: you can try below things.
1.  add `router.navigate(['/items'])` inside `ngOnDestroy(){}` function.
2. `window.onbeforeunload = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
}`

3. you can display an alert with a message that page will be redirected.

Comment: So I should add this in every component that I will have? I don't think is a good solution

Comment: By the way: `ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/items']);
    window.onbeforeunload = (event) => { event.preventDefault(); }
  }` this also doesn't work